# Concept of bicubic interpolation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, interpolation

I'm trying to do bicubic interpolation on an 8*8 matrix(image) shown below.

```
A = 10   20  30  40  50  60  70  80
    90  100 110 120 130 140 150 160
    170 180 190 200 210 220 230 240
    250  10  20  30  40  50  60  70
     80  90 100 110 120 130 140 150
    160 170 180 190 200 210 220 230
    240 250  10  20  30  40  50  60
     70  80  90 100 110 120 130 140
```

I used the following matlab code for it and I got an output

```
interp2(A,'bicubic')
```

But even after googling I'm not getting how to do it manually. Can anyone help me to get the idea using this example(only for few pixels)?

Comment: Take a look at Richard Alan Peters' slides on Image Resampling: https://ia700307.us.archive.org/7/items/Lectures_on_Image_Processing/EECE253_12_Resampling.pdf .  Specifically, look towards the very end.  They give some nice examples on bicubic interpolation and how to calculate the output pixels.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation JUST wikipedia